# ''went'' vs ''went off''

Tags: prepositions

A)'She left school and ***went off*** with a group of people who were against the war'

B)'She left school and ***went***  with a group of people who were against the war'

what is the difference in meaning between sentence a and sentence b ?

''WENT'' VS ''WENT OFF''

Answer (score 1):

### "Go off" and "went off" have several meanings.

([see this at Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/go%20off))

> > 1 : explode
> >
> > 2 : to burst forth or break out suddenly or noisily
> >
> > 3 : to go forth, out, or away : **leave**
> >
> > 4 : to undergo decline or deterioration
> >
> > 5 : to follow the expected or desired course : **proceed**;  *the party went off well*
> >
> > 6 : to make a characteristic noise : **sound**; *could hear the alarm going off*

### **The ESL Learner's Dictionary is more helpful:**

([see this at the Merriam-Webster ESL Learner's Dictionary](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/go))

> **go off [phrasal verb]**
>
> 1  a  of a bomb : to explode
>
> ```
> The building was evacuated before the bomb went off.
> ```
>
> b  of a gun : to shoot
>
> ```
> The gun went off accidentally.
> ```
>
> c  of an alarm : to begin to make a sudden loud noise
>
> ```
> I woke up when the alarm went off.
> ```
>
> 2  of lights, electricity, etc. : to stop working
>
> ```
> The lights in the building suddenly went off.
> ```
>
> 3  : to leave a place for a new place
>
> ```
> He went off to join the army after graduating from high school.
> She went off to America.
> ```
>
> 4  a  : to occur or happen
>
> ```
> The meeting went off as scheduled. [=the meeting happened when it was scheduled to happen]
> ```
>
> b  : to happen in a particular way
>
> ```
> The party went off well. [=the party was a success]
> The meeting went off poorly.
> ```
>
> 5  US, informal : to begin shouting at someone in an angry way —
>   usually + on
>
> ```
> Her boss went off on her because she was late again.
> ```
>
> 6  go off (someone or something) British : to stop liking (someone or
>   something)
>
> ```
> She used to like him but now she's gone off him completely.
> My boss has gone off the idea.
> ```
>
> 7  chiefly British a  go off with (someone) : to leave a spouse,
>   partner, etc., in order to live with and have a sexual relationship
>   with (someone)
>
> ```
> He left his wife and went off with [=ran off with] some young thing.
> ```
>
> b  go off with (something) : to take (something that belongs to
>   someone else) away with you : steal
>
> ```
> Someone went off with my pencil/wallet.
> ```

**So, according to Merriam-Webster:**

> A) "She left school and went off with a group of people who were
>   against the war."

Sentence A means that she left a place for a new place.  (ESL definition 3)

or perhaps

Sentence A ***implies*** that she left school for another place--to do something disreputable. (like ESL definition #7)

> B) "She left school and went with a group of people who were against
>   the war."

Sentence B could mean that she joined a group of people who had certain beliefs--without actually going to any particular location.

Answer (score 0):

"went off with" carries an implication that the group of people went somewhere with a definite objective in mind - perhaps to hold a discussion, or join a demonstration, or perhaps just to show by sticking together that they share a common viewpoint.

"went with" lacks that impression of a shared motivation - they just left left school together.