# What is the difference between "go" and "go off" is the sense of happening?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Tell me please if there is any difference in meaning between the following sentences.

> The job interview **went** well.
>
> The job interview **went off** well.

I think there is a difference because why would anyone add *off*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [''went'' vs ''went off''](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/206603/went-vs-went-off)

Answer (score 1):

The use of *go off* in your second example expresses idiomatically the same meaning as the first one:

***[To go off:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/go-off)***

> to happen in a particular way:
>
> - The protest march went off peacefully.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

The only place I'm used to hearing "went off" in this sense is in the expression "went off without a hitch," which means something went smoothly without any unexpected problems. I can't think of any other scenario where "went off" is preferable to or changes the meaning of "went."

Comment: In ***British** English*, your cited example is actually [just as common *without* "off" as with it.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=went+off+without+a+hitch%2Cwent+without+a+hitch&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwent%20off%20without%20a%20hitch%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwent%20without%20a%20hitch%3B%2Cc0) But the "verbal flourish" of using *to go **off*** in the sense of ***to go** = proceed / take place / come to fruition* is by no means limited to that *exact* context.